# "Poker size" cards: layout for easy printing

Tags: game-design, game-development

[Related to this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13877/what-does-poker-size-cards-mean/), I'm making a card game and I'm at the point where I'm designing the card layout.

Since changing this at a later stage will involve a lot of work, I would like to be sure I'm not making a mistake. I want to use "poker size" cards, but I've seen at least 4 different sizes for those: B8(62x88mm), 63x88mm, 63.5x88mm, and 2.5"x3.5" (63.5x88.9mm). The potential need for margins also affects the size of my layout. Several games have layouts that reach the card edge, but I am unsure if that is easily printable.

I'm in Canada if that makes a difference.

Comment: With all due respect, you should ask your manufacturer. It would be devastating to go off of faulty information.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Good advice, but I don't have a manufacturer (or publisher) yet and probably won't have one until the game is much further along.

Comment: You should know that art and graphic design that you do before seeking a licensing agreement with a publisher is almost certainly going to be a red flag and hurt your chances of getting signed. A publisher does more than just foot the bill for the print run - they usually handle art direction and creation of production files.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Thanks for letting me know, I will certainly keep it in mind when designing more games! However, this one I plan to keep small scale and under my own control. I'll probably give it as a free print&play, and if people like it I'll pay for a small run or do a kickstarter for a physical version. My next game should have more mass appeal and I'll plan it from the start as something I can let a publisher have control over.

Comment: What sort of purpose do these cards have in your game? It may be worth considering what players will be doing with them to help decide sizes. e.g. If they are going to be resource type cards they can probably be smaller (and cheaper), like Catan, since they won't have any text on them, or if they are going to be handled a lot (like a TCG) you could use a standard size like MTG's 63 x 88mm so players can use 3rd party card sleeves for protection.

Comment: @Malco Thanks, I have indeed opted for the MTG size. It also helps for prototyping/playtesting, as I can simply print on normal paper, cut the cards and place them in front of rigid cards inside sleeves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US Poker sized cards are 2.5" x 3.5". Of course, your art should be slightly larger than that if you want to have printing to the edge of the card. How much larger will depend on your print house, but 1/8" on each side (so 1/4" total in each dimension) should suffice, making the art 2.75" x 3.75".